# dplyr summarise keep NA if all summarised values are NA

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use dplyr summarise to sum counts by groups. Specifically I want to remove NA values if not all summed values are NA, but if all summed values are NA, I want to display NA. For example:

```
name <- c("jack", "jack", "mary", "mary", "ellen", "ellen")
number <- c(1,2,1,NA,NA,NA)

df <- data.frame(name,number)
```

In this case I want the following result:

- Jack = 3
- Mary = 1
- Ellen = NA

However if I set `na.rm = F`:

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(number = sum(number, na.rm = F))
```

The result is:

- Jack = 3
- Mary = NA
- Ellen = NA

And if i set `na.rm = T`:

```
df %>% group_by(name) %>% summarise(number = sum(number, na.rm = T))
```

The result is

- Jack = 3
- Mary = 1
- Ellen = 0

How can I solve this so that the cases with numbers and NA's get a number as output, but the cases with only NA's get NA as output.

Answer (score 8):

We can have a `if/else` condition - `if` `all` the values in 'number are `NA`, then return `NA` or `else` get the `sum`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(number = if(all(is.na(number))) NA_real_ else sum(number, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 6):

I was struggling with the same thing, so I wrote a solution into the package `hablar`. Try:

```
library(hablar)

df %>% group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(number = sum_(number))
```

which gives you:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  name  number
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 ellen    NA 
2 jack      3.
3 mary      1.
```

not that the only syntax difference is `sum_` which is a function that returns NA if all is NA, else removes NA and calcuules sum no-missing values.