# Sum/return NA when all values are NA

Tags: r, function, na

I'm trying to run a function on columns that have NA observations. When all observations are NA I would like it to return NA, but when only a fraction of rows has it, just apply na.rm=T. I've seen a few posts showing how to do this ([link_1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41470277/sum-non-na-elements-only-but-if-all-na-then-return-na), [link_2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54805570/dplyr-summarise-keep-na-if-all-summarised-values-are-na), [link_3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56473098/efficient-way-to-calculate-sum-or-return-na-if-all-values-are-na)), but none of them seem to work for my function and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
# data frame
species_1<- c(NA, 10, 40)
species_2<- c(NA, NA, 30)
species_3<- c(NA, NA, NA)
group<- c(1, 1, 1)

df<- data.frame(species_1, species_2, species_3, group)

# function argument
y_true_test<- c(30, 20, 20) 

# function
estimate = function(df, y_true, na.rm=T) {
  
  if (all(is.na(df))) df[NA_integer_] else
  
  sqrt(colSums((t(t(df) - y_true_test))^2, na.rm=T) / 3) / y_true_test * 100
  
}

# run
final<- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  group_modify( ~ as.data.frame.list(estimate(., y_true_test))) #species 3 returns '0' when it should be NA
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I guess your usage of `df[NA_integer_]` is one of the issue along with `all(is.na(df))#
[1] FALSE` i.e. it should be done by columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function was checking the `NA` on the whole dataset columns instead it should be by each column.  Here, is an option with `across`

```
library(dplyr)
names(y_true_test) <- grep("species", names(df), value = TRUE)
df %>%
   group_by(group) %>% 
   summarise(across(everything(), ~ if(all(is.na(.x))) NA_real_ else
     sqrt(sum((.x - y_true_test)^2, na.rm = TRUE)/n())/
                (y_true_test[cur_column()]) * 100), .groups = 'drop')
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 1 × 4
  group species_1 species_2 species_3
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      43.0      28.9        NA
```

---

If we want to modify the OP's function

```
estimate <- function(df, y_true, narm=TRUE) {
  
  i1 <- colSums(is.na(df)) == nrow(df)
  
  
   out <- sqrt(colSums((t(t(df) - y_true_test))^2,
        na.rm= narm) / 3) / y_true_test * 100
   out[i1] <- NA
   out
  
}
```

-testing

```
> df %>%
+   group_by(group) %>%
+   group_modify( ~ as.data.frame.list(estimate(., 
          y_true_test))) 
# A tibble: 1 × 4
# Groups:   group [1]
  group species_1 species_2 species_3
  <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
1     1      43.0      28.9        NA
```